# function detailed view is not redirecting to detailview.html page

Tags: python, django

i am trying to create a detailview in django.. when i am clicking in the listview items.. the url in browser is shoing id  ..  like http://localhost:8000/blog/2

but it is giving 404 page not found error.. please see..

views.py

```
    def detail_view(request, id=None):
    movie = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, id=id)

    context = {'BlogPost':BlogPost,
               }

    return render(request, 'blog/blogdetail.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
       path('list', BlogList.as_view(), name='list'),
       path('(?P<id>\d+)',detail_view, name='detail')
```

list.html

```
                    <div class="post-body">
                        {% for p in post %}
                        <a href="{{ p.id }}"><blockquote>{{p}}</br></br>{{p.Date}}</blockquote> </a>

                        {% endfor %}
```

the blogdetail.html page is in the same directory in which bloglist.html page is..

models.py

```
      class BlogPost(models.Model):


title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
writer = models.CharField(max_length=150,default='my dept')
category =models.CharField(max_length=150)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
post   = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
Date  = models.DateField( default=datetime.date.today)
```

Comment: Show us your `models.py`... Also check if id really exists..

Comment: You're confusing [path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#django.urls.path) and [re_path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#re-path) for the detail url.

Comment: hi @Melvyn i changed my urls as suggested by biplove in his answer but unfortunately it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
<a href="{% url 'detail' p.id %}"><blockquote>{{p}}</br></br>{{p.Date}}</blockquote> </a>
```

Here, we are adding path according to the name so that, it is not relative to the current path. [Refs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns)

#### EDIT

As pointed out by **Melvyn**. Use path like: [path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#django.urls.path) as this:

```
    path('list', BlogList.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('(<int:id>)',detail_view, name='detail')
```

Comment: Did you check if there is object `p`. If there is not `p` then `get_object_or_404()` raise `404 Not found` as id is not passed.

Comment: hi biplove can you please check it by teamviewer

Comment: Sorry ... I could not... use `print(id)` inside detailview before `get_object_or_404()` and see in terminal ... what you got printed